# C++ code not compiled correctly

Tags: c++

**I have window 8 and i code in dev c++ ..but i got some errors ..kindly help me to remove them**

Code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

main()
{

int AmerAge, AmaraAge;
cout<<"please enter AmerAge";
cin<<AmerAge;
cout<<"please enter AmaraAge";
cin<<AmaraAge;

if(AmerAge>AmaraAge)
cout<<"Amer is older than amara";
}
```

And compilation errors are

> 52    0   c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string In file included from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string

Comment: shouldnot main() be with some return type?

Comment: First, `conio.h` is not a C++ header, and you never use it anyway. And your error message makes no sense.

Comment: Most probably `#include<conio.h>` is the problem. Remove it.

Comment: Thanks .now this code runs correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first,

```
cin << AmerAge;
```

should be:

```
cin >> AmerAge;
```

I remember this with the memory aid: you input data *to* the variable, `cin >> var`, you output it *from* it, `cout << var`.

---

Secondly, `conio` is not a C++ header, it's not even a C header.

It's a blast from the past from Borland (or Invogue or Enchilada or whatever they call themselves nowadays).

And it has no place outside assignments in Indian educational institutions, where they seem to favour it despite having much more modern (and free and standards-compliant) options. It also doesn't complain about evils like not specifying a return type from `main()`.

---

Finally, you may want to go back and reread all those warnings you should have heeded when installing MinGW.

You know, the ones about installing into a path with spaces in it and how that's likely to screw up a large chunk of the toolchain :-)